# AspCorenet SignalR Client Wont Connect To LocalHost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am using this example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to create a hub.
My start up class:

```
 public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseSignalR(routes => 
        {
            routes.MapHub<TestHub>("/testhub");
        });

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });

    }
}
```

I use [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to get started with a WinForm Client using .net 4.6.1

My AspnetCore server runs on F5 and I get the "Hello World" response in my browser. I set up the SignalR client like this:

```
 private async void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
     .WithUrl("http://localhost:44306/testhub")
     .Build();
     connection.Closed += async (error) =>
     {
        await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0, 5) * 1000);
        await connection.StartAsync();
    };
```

However this code produses a timeout error on the Task.

```
        try
        {
            await connection.StartAsync();
            messagesList.Items.Add("Connection started");
            //connectButton.IsEnabled = false;
            //sendButton.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            messagesList.Items.Add(ex.Message);
        }
```

Does anyone know where my mistake is?

Comment: Is your AspnetCore server listening on localhost? is localhost configured in your working machine? maybe 127.0.0.1 could be better?

Comment: When I run on F5 Chrome starts and I get the "Hello World" I did try your suggestion but no luck.I am running in the same solution though and I wonder if that is causing trouble.

Comment: Did you check if there are errors in Chrome developer tools console? Maybe CORS?

Comment: Ahh When I run https://localhost:44306/testhub in Chrome getting Connectionid required so problem must be in WinForm Client thanks.

Comment: Seems you need to use https not http havn't come across that before with localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need to use https not http havn't come across that before with localhost.